# Getting a lot of errors when using Kinect SDK on OpenFrameworks project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect, openframeworks, kinect-sdk

Basically I'm trying to use the Kinect SDK on an OpenFrameworks project in Visual Studio 2012 Express but I'm getting a lot of errors when trying to include the NuiApi.

So what I've done until now is include the following directories:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\inc    in    Project -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\lib    in   Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\v1.8\lib\x86\Kinect10.lib in Project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input

And when I try to include the API like this:

```
#include <NuiApi.h>
```

I get a lot of errors the first one is this:

```
Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'INuiAudioBeam'   c:\program files\microsoft sdks\kinect\v1.8\inc\nuisensor.h 46  1   mySketch
```

I also get the same error if I try adding the ofxKinectNui addon.

I'm using the Kinect SDK 1.8

Comment: If you're using OF, why not just use it's ofxKinect wrapper for libfreenect?

Comment: Because I need skeleton tracking functionality, that's why I also tried using ofxKinectNui

Comment: Oh, yes, I should have figured.

Comment: Well, I have used both Kinect SDK and OpenNI to do skeleton tracking, but not with OF in the mix; however, there is evidence of OF working with OpenNI here: http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/openni-skeleton-tracking/5125/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the ofxUI addon I was using for the GUI, it worked when I removed this addon.
I have not found a way to get both working at the same time.